# What are the optimal parameters for the pycaret function setup?

Tags: python, pycaret

Used in Pycaret's preprocessing function setup ()
Please tell me the recommended parameters.

Depending on the type of input data
How parameters
Should I change it?

For example, by classification, regression, clustering
Should I change the parameters?
Or will it change on a different basis?

Thank you.

Comment: To get a better response, try demonstrating what you have tried, whats working and what isn't. This will allow the community to better gauge the type of answer required.

Answer (score 0):

In the Pycaret Setup there are several options, how to pre-process your data. Several default options are already defined. For example One Hot Encoding for categorical variables, by `normalise=True` it uses by default ‘zscore’ to normalize the data etc.

There is no proper default way, how to preprocess your data, because all datasets are unique and every of them needs to be threated individually. From an EDA you can get a sense, in which way you need to pre-process the data or simpy trail error experiments could help as well (at least to estabilish the base-line). For certain algorithms there are considerations.

Here is the set-up for classification tasks explained: [https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/classification.htm](https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/classification.html)l